# IBM Cognos Transformer Data sources

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

It's possible to add an Oracle connection to Cognos Transformer in the data source type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, first you have to create a Data Source Connection to Oracle in the Cognos Analytics management console.

Then you publish a package with the Oracle tables that you want to use for your cube.

Then you make Cognos reports linked to this package.

You can then use these reports from Cognos Transformer to build your cubes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the documentation which outlines all the available data source for IBM Cognos PowerPlay transformer.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=model-data-source-types#DataSources